# Android Emulator not working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, emulation

I was built Android 7.0.0_r14 and then emulated but failed.
The problem is stopping "emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized" and just staying black screen. 
I don't know what to do..

Here is log.

```
jinscorp@jinscorp:~/sdk/emulator$ ./emulator @Test7 -verbos
unknown option: -verbos
please use -help for a list of valid options
jinscorp@jinscorp:~/sdk/emulator$ ./emulator @Test7 -verbose
emulator:Android emulator version 26.0.0.0 (build_id 3833124)
emulator:Found AVD name 'Test7'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator:argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a/

emulator:Probing for /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a/

emulator:try dir /home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator:  Found directory: /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a/

emulator:  Found directory: /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a/

emulator:GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "@Test7"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel @Test7 -verbose
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 24
emulator: Read property file at /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'nexus_6' in directory: /home/jinscorp/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -skin nexus_6
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/jinscorp/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.1.1
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/jinscorp/sdk/skins//nexus_6/layout'
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: Using default value for kernel Contiguous Memory Allocation.
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.1.1
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.cpu.ncore = 2
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = true
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1440
  hw.lcd.height = 2560
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 560
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
  hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 384
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  kernel.path = /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-ranchu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 800m
  avd.name = Test7
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "127.0.1.1"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[06] = "cortex-a15"
emulator: argv[07] = "-machine"
emulator: argv[08] = "type=ranchu"
emulator: argv[09] = "-m"
emulator: argv[10] = "1536"
emulator: argv[11] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[12] = "560"
emulator: argv[13] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[14] = "/home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-ranchu"
emulator: argv[15] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[16] = "/home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[17] = "-object"
emulator: argv[18] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[19] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[20] = "overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=sdcard,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[21] = "-device"
emulator: argv[22] = "virtio-blk-device,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=1,id=userdata,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-device,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=2,id=cache,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/cache.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-device,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[31] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[32] = "overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=3,id=system,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/system.img.qcow2,read-only"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-blk-device,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[35] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[36] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[39] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[40] = "user,id=mynet2,net=10.0.3.0/24"
emulator: argv[41] = "-device"
emulator: argv[42] = "virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet2"
emulator: argv[43] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[44] = "-L"
emulator: argv[45] = "/home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[46] = "-append"
emulator: argv[47] = "qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu keep_bootcon earlyprintk=ttyAMA0 android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1"
emulator: argv[48] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[49] = "/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel -dns-server 127.0.1.1 -serial null -cpu cortex-a15 -machine type=ranchu -m 1536 -lcd-density 560 -kernel /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-ranchu -initrd /home/jinscorp/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -drive overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=sdcard,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread -drive overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=1,id=userdata,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread -drive overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=2,id=cache,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/cache.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread -drive overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=3,id=system,file=/home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/system.img.qcow2,read-only -device virtio-blk-device,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet -netdev user,id=mynet2,net=10.0.3.0/24 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet2 -show-cursor -L /home/jinscorp/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -append 'qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu keep_bootcon earlyprintk=ttyAMA0 android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1' -android-hw /home/jinscorp/.android/avd/Test7.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '384m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '560'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
```

Comment: increase heap size of your emulator

Comment: I changed heapsize 256 to 1024 but not solved.

Comment: do you have the exact system image installed check by starting your sdk manager?

Comment: I installed image by sdk manager and then i replace system.img, ramdisk.img, userdata.img that are built by me. 
They succeeded in building without errors. In my opinion, the problem is fingerprint. because i was succeeded in android 5.0 ver but android 6.0 or 7.0 failed. And emulator just staying "emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
"

Answer (score 0):

Emulator uses custom system images, built from its own set of CLs. I don't think there's a tag for any of the CLs, so it's pretty much impossible to reproduce the very same image as released with Android Studio and SDK.

As a workaround, you could try replacing only specific binaries on the released image with your custom versions - this way it should boot, unless you really break something in Android.

P.S. android_hw_fingerprint_init has nothing to do with your issue - it's just some subsystem that was the last to successfully initialize. Nothing else did - Android hung.

P.P.S. You can try adding -show-kernel siwtch for more logging, and running 'adb logcat' in a parallel terminal for diagnostics from inside the Android OS.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I try it.